# Is it possible to convert R to AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, r

I've been given a huge mathematical class written in R that I'm trying to translate to AS3. I've seen that there are libraries available for R that convert the movie into a SWF but I've yet to find something that spits out an AS3 class. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: which R exactly are we talking about?

Comment: R is a mathematical programming language: http://www.r-project.org/

Comment: So you want something that will automatically convert R code to Actionscript code?  Happy to be proved wrong but I think you may be overly optimistic.

Comment: Well it looks like R can be exported into a SWF, going to try this and decode it. I know that people have built interfaces for C and what not, hopefully someone's done it for AS3.

Comment: @Ahmed : Then we're talking about the same R. Good luck I'd say... PS : There are interfaces for C. That's not the same as conversion from R-code to C-code...

Comment: I too think this is very very unlikely to work easily ... can you give more details?

Comment: For what it's worth `library(sos); findFn("actionscript")` gets 4 hits, 2 essentially false positives and 2 to `RJSONIO::asJSVars` which can apparently "Serialize R objects as Javsscript/ActionScript variables".  I have no idea if that's actually useful.

Comment: What does this "huge mathematical class" do? Can you point us to it, or show us bits of it? And can you show us small chunks of ActionScript that do similar things? I'm wondering what the syntax is like. Also: NEVER convert from language A to language B without a comprehensive test suite.

Comment: Is there a reason to redo this function in AS3?  Why not have AS3 communicate with R, or vice versa, by passing data or results back and forth?  You could probably have data passed via an intermediary, like Java (see the rJava package), or through some other approach, like using RApache, Rserve, or RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say no. You're own your own.